# Combine rows on PySpark by continues ranges

Tags: pyspark

Assume I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
| username| start_range| end_range| user_type|
 ---------------------------------------------
|  a      |   1        |  99      |  admin   |
|  a      |   100      |  200     |  admin   |
|  b      |   100      |  150     |  reader  |
|  a      |   300      |  350     |  admin   |
|  b      |   200      |  300     |  reader  |
```

And I want to combine rows by continues ranges to get the following `DataFrame`:

```
| username| start_range| end_range| user_type|
 ---------------------------------------------
|  a      |   1        |  200     |  admin   |
|  b      |   100      |  150     |  reader  |
|  a      |   300      |  350     |  admin   |
|  b      |   200      |  300     |  reader  |
```

I want to avoid using `UDF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to identify and mark rows that can be continued and then group them.

This solution is more efficient than Anna's as it does not use an explode.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

column_names = ['username', 'start_range', 'end_range', 'user_type']
data = [
    ('a', 1, 99, 'admin'),
    ('a', 100, 200, 'admin'),
    ('b', 100, 150, 'admin'),
    ('a', 300, 350, 'reader'),
    ('b', 200, 300, 'admin'),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=column_names)

def merge_by_start_end(df):
    w = Window.orderBy(['username', 'user_type', 'start_range'])
    
    # Used to test whether an entry can be continued
    df = df.withColumn('end_range_lag_p1',
        F.lag(F.col('end_range') + 1, default=-100).over(w))
    
    # Index by cumulative sum, such that entries that can be continued get the same index
    is_entry_terminal = (F.col('end_range_lag_p1') != F.col('start_range')).cast('long')
    df = df.withColumn('merge_index', F.sum(is_entry_terminal).over(w))
    
    return df.groupBy(['username', 'user_type', 'merge_index']).agg(
        F.min('start_range').alias('start_range'),
        F.max('end_range').alias('end_range'),
    ).drop('merge_index')

merge_by_start_end(df)
```

Comment: How can I see the values of 'is_entry_terminal' as print, display and show none are working with this.

Comment: @PythonLearner You can't print `F.col()` before it has been attached to a DataFrame. Use `df.withColumn('is_entry_terminal', is_entry_terminal)` and print `df`.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in three steps. First, explode your data for each value between the ranges. Then, create id for each sequence with continues ranges, then group by username and id and get the final table.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data =  [("a", 1, 99, "admin"),
         (  "a", 100, 200, "admin"),
         (  "b", 100, 150, "reader"),
         (  "a", 300, 350, "admin"),
         (  "b", 200, 300, "reader")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, 
        schema=["username", "start_range", "end_range", "user_type"])

# explode data between ranges
df1 = (df
   .withColumn("seq", F.sequence("start_range", "end_range"))
   .withColumn("tag", F.explode("seq")))

# tag each group with id 
w = Window.partitionBy("username").orderBy("tag")
w1 = (Window
      .partitionBy("username")
      .orderBy("tag")
      .rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

df2 = (df1
   .withColumn("tag_lag", F.lag("tag").over(w))
   .fillna(0)
   .withColumn("diff", F.col("tag")-F.col("tag_lag")-1)
   .withColumn("id", F.sum("diff").over(w1)))

# group by id and get start_range and end_range 
df3 = (df2
        .groupBy("username", "user_type", "id")
        .agg(F.min("tag").alias("start_range"), 
             F.max("tag").alias("end_range"))
      ).select("username", "start_range", "end_range", "user_type")
```

Comment: I am afraid that this solution won't scale in a wide range scenario. For example, if the start_range is 0 and the end_range is1M for a specific row, it resolves in creating a million redundant rows.